# number to date conversion in excel (weird format)

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have collected some details from sql and it shows a birthdates as following (each line represents a different birthdate):

```
-294022800
649119600
-138675600
49158000
32396400
631152000
-2147483648
731894400
-408067200
522025200
```

I was trying to change them in excel using this formula:

```
=DATE(INT(A1/10000),INT((A1-10000*INT(A1/10000))/100),A1-(100*INT(A1/100)))
```

But it didnt work well, it must be in different format. Do you know what sort of format it is and how to convert it to date in excel? why some of numbers are negatives?
Can this be the EPOCH format? how to change it to normal human date in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix timestamps can be converted with this formula

`=A1/86400+DATE(1970,1,1)`

The Unix timestamp is seconds since 1/1/1970 so birthdates before then would be negative. [one of the birthdates translates to 1901 - is that right? You'll have problems if any of the dates are before 1900 because Excel doesn't recognise those dates]

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that they are unix timestamps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

In excel, you can use something like:

```
=(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

Although, you will have to watch out for the fact that your datetimes seem to include daylight savings offsets. (Some of them are multiples of a day (24*60*60), but others are an hour out). I'm not sure why you have a non-hour multiple in there (-2147483648), possibly some quirk of the original system.

Source: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/converting_unix_timestamps/

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out. This is the formula:

```
=(A1-(4*3600))/86400+25569
```

Comment: Presumably the 4*3600 is a timezone adjustment?

Comment: right. but I prefer your answer @barryhoudini :) more generic. thakns